# One Point Compactification

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Suppose X is a path-connected, locally compact, Hausdorff space and Y is its one-point compactification.  Let G be the fundamental group of X and H be the fundamental group of Y.  Is it true that the embedding of X into Y always induces a monomorphism G->H?  More generally, what is the relationship between G and H?

Answer (score 13):

More generally, if A and X<sub>0</sub> are any finite CW complexes, and f : A → X<sub>0</sub> is any map, let Y be the mapping cone of f, and let X be Y with the cone point removed; then Y is the one-point compactification of X, and the inclusion X<sub>0</sub> → X is a homotopy equivalence.  (David's example is the case A = X<sub>0</sub> = S<sup>1</sup>, f = id.)  So any map X → Y which is the mapping cone of something is homotopy equivalent to a one-point compactification.

I don't think you can realize any map of groups as the induced map on π<sub>1</sub> of a mapping cone (0 → Z/2Z?) but you can realize (G → 0, 0 → a free group, ...)

Answer (score 6):

It is not always a monomorphism. Let X be R^2 \setminus { (x,y) : x^2 + y^2 < 1 }. Then X has fundamental group the integers, but Y is contractible.

Comment: I think you mean { (x,y) : x^2 + y^2 < 1}. i.e. you want to leave the boundary circle there. Then Y is contractible. Otherwise Y is a pinched torus and also has fundamental group the integers (although the induced map is zero). 

Comment: You are right. I have edited to fix the error.

Comment: I think the good old inversion z |-> 1/z makes this easier to see: i.e., just take the closed unit disk in the plane with the origin removed.  

